# Jenkins is not using all CPU cores with Mac OS X slave

Tags: c++, macos, jenkins

I have a Jenkins 2.60.1 master with Mac OSX Jenkins slave.
I am trying to use Jenkins to trigger automatic build task on a c++ project.

command is as simple as executing a shell command "make -j8 my_project".

When the build task is triggered by Jenkins, the compile time is much longer comparing to execute make command directly in terminal.

The CPU usage is always low and looks like Jenkins is not using all CPU cores.

How do I enforce Jenkins to use all CPU cores to speed up compiling?

Comment: why would you think Jenkins has anything to do with this? Jenkins is just executing you make command. Its your compiler toolchain that could benefit from multiple cores, and the reasons it isn't depend on a lot more information than you posted.

Comment: I also tried to execute exactly the same make command inside terminal. I can see my CPU usage of all 8 cores are running >90%. But the same command triggered by Jenkins has very low CPU usage and most of time it only have a few cores running. Just wondering if there is a possibility that the subprocess spawn by Jenkins is somehow limited to a few cores.